# How to get jenkins to use current npm version?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

A project I am on has a Jenkins server to which I don't have remote access.
The server admin has installed npm 5.8 using `npm install -g npm`.
Executing `npm -v` reports a version of 5.8.

However, during the Jenkins build process, `npm -v` reports a version of 5.6 which is the version that shipped with the installed version of NodeJS.

Can someone assist me in what I should be asking the admin to change?

Comment: I think as a first step, I would want to compare the output of `command -v npm` and `env` both from the admin's teminal and from the Jenkins job, in addition to `npm -v`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The admin should be able to install the [Jenkins NodeJS Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs) which allows you to handle several different installations (in different versions) of NodeJS. This way you can address the version of NodeJS & npm you want to use from the Job configuration, as the correct folder is temporarily added to the PATH variable.

There is a walkthrough guide on the [wiki page of the plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Following steps will help you:

- If it is windows machine, you better to restart the node after you install anything. Then only Jenkins can get the updated environment variables.
- Verify the Environment variable pointed to correct version folder.
- If you know the updated installed path then you can create local environment variable at job level using following command.

> env.NODE_HOME =
>   "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm"